# Check if column value is higher than other rows with corresponding columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In SQL Server, I'm having problems checking multiple rows in a check constraint.

For a bidding system, there is a table with these columns:

```
ObjectID [INT] 
BidAmount [NUMERIC(9,2)] 
User [VARCHAR(40)] 
Date [DATETIME]
```

I want to make sure that an inserted bid has a higher `BidAmount` than the other bids for this `ObjectID`.

I tried doing this with a user-defined function in the check-constraint, however this turned out to be very unreliable (sometimes an insert was allowed and sometimes it was denied. There didn't seem to be a pattern).

The Bid table:

```
CREATE TABLE Bid 
(
    ObjectID INT NOT NULL,
    BidAmount NUMERIC(9,2) NOT NULL,
    User VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    Date DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_Bod 
        PRIMARY KEY (ObjectID, BidAmount),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Bod_User 
        FOREIGN KEY (User) REFERENCES User (Username),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Bod_Object 
        FOREIGN KEY (ObjectID) REFERENCES Object (ObjectID),
    CONSTRAINT AK_Bod_Gebruikersmoment UNIQUE (User, Date),
    CONSTRAINT AK_Bod_Voorwerpmoment UNIQUE (ObjectID, Date),
    CONSTRAINT CK_Bodhoogte 
        CHECK (BidAmount > dbo.krijgMinimaleBod(ObjectID, Date))
)
```

The user-defined function I tried to use:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.krijgMinimaleBod (@ObjectID INT)
RETURNS NUMERIC(9,2)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @highestBid NUMERIC(9,2)

    SELECT @highestBid = ISNULL(MAX(BidAmount), V.StartPrice)
    FROM Object V
    LEFT JOIN Bid B ON B.ObjectID = V.ObjectID
    WHERE V.ObjectID = @ObjectID
    GROUP BY V.ObjectID, V.StartPrice;

    RETURN @highestBid
END
```

How would I go about preventing the system from having rows inserted with a `BidAmount` that's lower than the other amounts on the same product?

Comment: Beside your question: Are you sure the line SELECT highestBid = ISNULL(MAX(BidAmount), V.StartPrice) is correct? Shouldn't it be SELECT highestBid = MAX(ISNULL(BidAmount, V.StartPrice))?

Comment: @JonasMetzler Thank you for your comment. I'm sure this works, in fact, when calling `SELECT dbo.krijgMinimaleBod([randomObject])` will always give the right value.

Comment: you can't enforce this with a constraint. You would need to use a serializable lock when doing the insert. Probably best off concurrency wise to just allow the inserts to succeed and ensure that the reading queries filter out invalid bids

Comment: The `CK_Bodhoogte` constraint refers non-existsing columns `Voorwerp, Datum`. Please correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by using a trigger in T-SQL.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Bid_HighEnough ON dbo.Bod
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 'Wrong'
                FROM Inserted I INNER JOIN Bid B
                ON I.ObjectID = B.ObjectID
                INNER JOIN Object V
                ON I.ObjectID = V.ObjectID
                WHERE I.BidAmount < V.StartPrice OR I.BidAmount < B.BidAmount
    BEGIN
        THROW 50000, 'No bids allowed lower than previous bids.', 1
    END
```

Thank you for your comments.

Comment: This can work, but you need to carefully consider your transaction isolation level before putting this into production. For something like a bidding system where real money is involved you want to make sure two transactions aren't running at the same time potentially creating conflicting results.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I would personally recommend that you DO NOT try to coordinate bids in this way because its complicated and unnecessary. Instead allow all bids submitted to be written to the table, and determine the highest bidder after the fact based on the bid values and timestamp of the bids. This way even if you have two bids for $10 at nearly the same time you can simply:
SELECT TOP(1) Name, BidAmount
FROM Bids
WHERE BidAmount = (select MAX(BidAmount) from Bids where AuctionID = @AuctionID)
order by BidTimeStamp ASC

Comment: @NickFotopoulos thank you for your comments. I'll look into the isolation level. I see your point in allowing all bids to be inserted, however this might create problems in other parts of the system. For example, there is this log where end users can see previous bids. This list is supposed to only show valid bids. Also there is a mandatory increase, i.e. a minimum amount a bid should be higher than the previous bid (I've left it out of my question to keep it more general). How would you go about this, would you keep the trigger or apply all this business logic in the application?

Comment: Its hard to say without knowing more about the existing architecture, but using a SERIALIZABLE isolation level will probably do the trick in terms of making sure one bid completes before the next can start. Just have to make sure your queries are well written to minimize lock escalation. If a particular Object has a lot of bids it can cause the row locks to escalate to page or even table locks which can cause site wide concurrency issues:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/performance/resolve-blocking-problems-caused-lock-escalation

Comment: Presumably you want the last condition to be `I.BidAmount <= B.BidAmount`, not `I.BidAmount < B.BidAmount`, so that subsequent bidders can't match the current highest bid. Or, as mentioned in a comment, `I.BidAmount < B.BidAmount + MininumBidIncrement`.

Answer (score 0):

`CHECK Constraints` are excellent for checks made on a single row. Things get complex when trying to access other rows, on the target table or others.

I strongly feel that enforcing this logic is not really a responsibility of the table. The bids are what they are. You could have bid A=10$, a subsequent bid B=20$, but then an error was detected and you actually have to update bid A to 30$. What should happen then? Probably nothing; the alternative would be to extend your question to include updates, leading to even more complex situtations.

Instead, it is the responsibility of the user that runs `INSERT`s to do that correctly. The more organized way is to use a procedure to perform insertions from the user/application. This proc can have a check prior to insert, and `throw` without using a trigger.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I eventually solved this issue using a trigger.

Comment: Careful with your updates...